# Python code is not running

Tags: python

I was reading LEARN PYTHON THE HARD WAY by Zed A. Shaw. In chapter 13 I got the following code

```
from sys import argv
script, first, second, third = argv
print("The script is called:",script)
print("Your first variable is:",first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is :",third)
```

I tried to run this on spyder but the error occurs.I gonna paste the last lines of spyder console
`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)`

Please help me to figure out the issue, thanks.

Comment: 1. If you get errors, you need to post them here. Saying that you get errors, then not saying what they are isn't very helpful. 2. How are you running the script? Are you passing any arguments?

Comment: Please have a look at this [argv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263951/what-is-argv-and-what-does-it-do)

Comment: "I was reading LEARN PYTHON THE HARD WAY by Zed A. Shaw. In chapter 13 " The necessary explanation is **in the surrounding text**. I happen to think that LPTHW is a terrible textbook, but it at least does a reasonable job of explaining what it's talking about, at the times it talks about them. Where it doesn't, it's because the author is expecting the reader to **use a search engine** with relatively obvious terms in order to understand the concept.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't passing in any command line arguments when you run the script, even though it's expecting 3 arguments. You're getting an error because you're trying to extract more values out of `args` than it contains.

Command line arguments are data that you're giving to the program. Just pass some dummy data as arguments when you run your script:

```
python your_script_here.py 1 2 3
```

The `1 2 3` are the arguments being passed.

My example was modified from [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm). It's worth a read-over.

Answer (score 1):

```
# your_code.py
from sys import argv
script, first, second, third = argv
print("The script is called:",script)
print("Your first variable is:",first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is :",third)
```

You can run it this way :

```
python your_code.py one two three
```

So you get :

```
The script is called: your_code.py
Your first variable is: one
Your second variable is: two
Your third variable is : three
```

Regards

Comment: There were leading letters before import, it's been corrected I suppose !

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you are not passing any arguments when running the file.
Trying passing arguments while running the file. An example

```
python foo.py 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, `sys.argv` is a list which contains the `command-line` arguments passed to the script.

So for instance you could create a python file named `testingArguments.py` which would print the arguments parsed from the `command-line`.

The code for this may simply look something like:

```
from sys import argv
print(argv)
```

then from the command line, if you ran the command:

```
python testingArguments.py arg1 arg2 3
```

then it would print out the arguments in a `list` so:

```
['testingArguments.py', 'arg1', 'arg2', '3']
```

what your code does, is get this `list` in the same way, then unpacks it just like you can a `list` not from `sys.argv`:

```
a, b, c, d = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

now `a=1`, `b=2`, `c=3` and `d=4`.

so hopefully you can see now that altogether, your code just prints out the four arguments passed at the command line which are the script name and `3` more arguments as above.

The `error` that you are getting:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)
```

is because you are not passing in these `3` extra variable so `sys.argv` can't be unpacked into `4` as it only has one element: the script name. Hence the last bit: `(expected 4, got 1)`.

Hope this helps!